# Add element at top of an array not working properly

Tags: java

so i want to add an element at the top of the array, it works for the first value i insert but if i insert another the one it doesn't get saved to the array. any help would be much appreciated ,thanks in advance. 
this is my push function

```
private static final int STACK_SIZE = 10;
private double [] stack;
protected int top;
public ArrayStack() {
    stack = new double[STACK_SIZE];
    top = -1;// stack is empty
}

@Override
public void push (double p) throws DataStructureException {
    if (!isFull()) {    
        top++;
        stack[top] = p;
    }
    else
        System.err.println( "Stack is full: cannot push " + p ); 
    }
```

Comment: Please post the `isFull()` method

Comment: What is the error

Comment: the error is the first element gets inserted at the top of the array but the second element  gets inserted in the index 1, i want to insert every item in the index 0 and push the other next to it

Comment: Your `push` method is fine as it is.  Why would you want to add all elements to index 0?

Comment: Arrays simply don't work that way, which is why you have the `top` index.

Comment: You _can_, of course, if you must, have all the new items go in at index zero.  Use `System.arraycopy` (or a carefully designed `for` loop) to move all the existing items at indices zero through `top` up to indices 1 through `top + 1`, increment `top`, and store the new item at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your condition here

```
if (!isFull())
{   
    top++;
    stack[top] = p;
}
```

you increment the index where you're going to add the next element, not the actual position of the element. Since `top` value is 1 on the second call, the element will be added to `stack[1]`.

I recommend you take a look at some other data structures. Lists for example have a method to add an element to the start of a list which would solve your issue:

```
list.add(0,p)
```

Another alternative is using `Deque` which also has a method to insert at the beginning

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 0):

you were increasing the top count before adding , so instead use  post increment as index

```
 if (!isFull()) {    
          if(top==-1){top++};
            stack[top++] = p;
        }
```